# CASTing and converting functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert `dd.mm.yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

```
select convert(date,CAST(WEEK_DATE as nvarchar(220)), 120) 
from z_fact
```

Error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What is the type of `WEEK_DATE`, and can you show us sample data?

Comment: ex:  15.03.18 (format is dd.mm.yy)

Comment: nvarchar is the type of week_date

Comment: The lesson you should take away from this is to store dates as DateTime, not strings.

Answer (score 3):

Since your date is actually text, you must first convert it to a bona fide date using `CONVERT`.  Then, use `CONVERT` on that date a second time to generate the text output you want.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(datetime, '15.03.18', 4), 120);
```

### Demo

Note that it is generally bad practice to store your dates as text.  Hopefully you can use my answer to tidy up your table.  For example, you could add a new datetime column `new_dt` and then update it using:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET new_dt = CONVERT(datetime, old_dt, 4);
```

Don't worry about the internal format used by SQL Server.  If you still need to display `yyyy-mm-dd` output, then use `CONVERT` again, as I did in my first query.

Comment: Thanks, i want to convert all the date in the week_date column from dd.mm.yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: No.  Don't worry about the internal format of the date, just store as _dates_, period.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen... I would recommend to specify the length of varchar while conversations.

Comment: "Note that it is generally bad practice to store your dates as text." I think it's **always** a bad idea... Even if you are dealing with dates that are outside the scope of `DateTime2` (A.D or after 9999), it's better to store the dates as numbers (Like SQL Server does internally) then as strings. Also, I wouldn't recommend `datetime` but `datetime2` - [Here's why](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/). All that being said, still this is a solid answer so +1.

Comment: @ZoharPeled In some databases, such as SQLite, there is no formal date type, so text is the only option for storing dates.  There, it is absolutely critical that the text dates be in ISO format, so that they will sort and compare properly.  Not so relevant to SQL Server, but just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
declare @dt NVARCHAR(12) = '15.03.18' 
SELECT  CONVERT(DATE,@dt,3)
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, i want to convert all the date in the week_date from dd.mm.yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: by mistake i would have clicked when copied your code.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but the `3` style in format expects `/` and not `.` as a date separator. You want to use `4` instead - `convert(date, @dt, 4)`. Even if your code worked, it's only a partial answer at best.